# does std::vector copy/move elements when re-sizing?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, move-semantics

I was messing around with move c'tors for a learning / refresh exercise and I came across something unexpected to me. Below I have a class `person` that contains a `std::string m_name;`. I am using this as a test class for copy/move c'tors.

Here is the code for quick reference:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class person
{
public:
    std::string m_name;
    explicit person(const std::string &name) : m_name(name)
    {
        std::cout << "created " << m_name << std::endl;     
    }
    
    ~person()
    {
        std::cout << "destroyed " << m_name << std::endl;       
    }   
    
    person(const person &other) : m_name(other.m_name)
    {
        m_name += ".copied";
        std::cout << "copied " << other.m_name << " -> " << m_name << std::endl;
    }
    
    person(const person &&other) noexcept : m_name(std::move(other.m_name))
    {
        m_name += ".moved";
        std::cout << "moved " << other.m_name << " -> " << m_name << std::endl;
    }   
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<person> people;
    people.reserve(10);
    
    std::cout << "\ncopy bob (lvalue):" << std::endl;
    person bob{"bob"};
    people.push_back(bob);

    std::cout << "\nmove fred (lvalue):" << std::endl;
    person fred{"fred"};
    people.push_back(std::move(fred));

    std::cout << "\ntemp joe (rvalue):" << std::endl;
    people.push_back(person{"joe"});
    
    std::cout << "\nterminating:" << std::endl;
}
```

This gives me the output that I would expect (mostly, except why std::string contents is not "moved"?): https://godbolt.org/z/-J_56i

Then I remove the std::vector `reserve` so that std::vector has to "grow" as I am adding elements. Now I get something that I really don't expect: https://godbolt.org/z/rS6-mj

Now I can see that bob is copied and then moved when fred is added and then moved again when joe is added. I was under the impression that std::vector "moved" when it has to reallocate space. But I thought that it did a memory copy/move, not an object-by-object copy/move. I really did not expect it to call the move constructor.

Now if I remove the move c'tor, I find that bob is copied three times!: https://godbolt.org/z/_BxnvU
This seems really inefficient.

From cplusplus.com:

**push_back()**

> Add element at the end Adds a new element at the end of the vector,
> after its current last element. The content of val is copied (or
> moved) to the new element.
>
> This effectively increases the container size by one, which causes an
> automatic reallocation of the allocated storage space if -and only if-
> the new vector size surpasses the current vector capacity.

**resize()**

> Resizes the container so that it contains n elements.
>
> If n is smaller than the current container size, the content is
> reduced to its first n elements, removing those beyond (and destroying
> them).
>
> If n is greater than the current container size, the content is
> expanded by inserting at the end as many elements as needed to reach a
> size of n. If val is specified, the new elements are initialized as
> copies of val, otherwise, they are value-initialized.
>
> If n is also greater than the current container capacity, an automatic
> reallocation of the allocated storage space takes place.
>
> Notice that this function changes the actual content of the container
> by inserting or erasing elements from it.

I guess it does not really describe "how" it does the reallocation, but surely a memory copy is the fastest way to move the vector to its newly allocated memory space?

So why are the copy/move c'tors called when std::vector is added to instead of a memory copy?

A side note/question: (any maybe this should be a separate question): In person move c'tor why is `moved fred -> fred.moved` printed and not `moved -> fred.moved`. It appears that the std::string move assignment does not really "move" the data...

Comment: `but surely a memory copy is the fastest way to move the vector to its newly allocated memory space?` You can't just memcpy C++ objects. What if they contain pointers to itself?

Comment: that is a a good point, that means that allocating to a vector can get be worse then I thought! - especially if the class you create does not have move c'tors :o. I guess always reserve some space if you can :)

Comment: This _problem_ might get solved soon: https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2018/07/18/announcing-trivially-relocatable/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it needs to relocate, something similar to [`std::move`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/move)`(xold.begin(), xold.end(), xnew.begin());` will be used. It depends on the value type and the vector usually does its own internal placement new . but it'll move if it can move.

Your move constructor

```
person(const person &&other) noexcept;
```

has a flaw though: `other` should not be `const` since it must be allowed to change `other` to *steal* its resources. In this move constructor

```
person(person&& other) noexcept : m_name(std::move(other.m_name)) {}
```

the `std::string`s own move constructor will do something similar to this:

```
string(string&& other) noexcept : 
    the_size(other.the_size),
    data_ptr(std::exchange(other.data_ptr, nullptr))
{}
```

You also need to add a move assignment operator:

```
person& operator=(person &&other) noexcept;
```

Comment: ah thanks makes sense to me now :). I did not add the move-assignment to keep this as simple as possible. Re const'ing the move c'tor - it is const already or am I missing something there?

Comment: @code_fodder Great! :) I added a little more about the need to make it non-`const` to the answer.

Comment: I mis-read your const comment. I removed const from the move c'tor (I thought you said need to add const) and now I get the correct output from fred: `moved  -> fred.moved`, before it was: `moved fred -> fred.moved`, meaning it had not actually moved  - that solves that little misunderstanding - thanks!

Comment: @code_fodder Oh, I missed that you misread it :-) Great that it worked out. You are welcome!